# use of int32_t in c or c++?

Tags: c++, c

I have two questions in my mind now:

1. Firstly, why do we need int32_t as we already have different variation for it like short int unsigned int and etc.
2. Secondly does the use of this type of fixed size types makes programs portable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h

Comment: Portability, serialization, marshalling..... there are a number of times when you want an *exact known size* of all of your types

Comment: Because the types `long long` and `long` and `int` and `short` are defined to be of a *minimum* size. If you **must** have 32 bits then on an architecture where `int` is 16 bits `int32_t` will do the job.

Comment: There are many portability concerns unrelated to integer representation and range.

Comment: Use of `int32_t` can _decrease_ portability as a rare platform might be using non-2's complement integers.  Of course, if the code needs 2's complement to run right, that is good.

Comment: @nathan That's one of the rare cases that applies for both languages equally.

Answer (score 4):

1) int32_t provides **exact 32 bit integer**. This is important because you can port your applications to different platforms without rewriting algorithm (if they will compile and yes, int is not always 16 or 32 or 64 bit wide, check C Reference). Check [nice self-explanatory page about stdint.h types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

2) Probably, yes

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Firstly, why do we need int32_t as we already have different variation for it like short int unsigned int and etc.

Because `short int`, `unsigned int`, etc aren't portable among architectures.

If you mean exactly 32 bits, just say that explicitely. Otherwise you might end up using 64 bits just using the `unsigned int` with a different CPU architecture.

> 2. Secondly does the use of this type of fixed size types makes programs portable?

Yes, as mentioned above.

Comment: `int32_t` also insures 2's complement.  `int` does not.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types
1 The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N , no padding
bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed
integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.*

Comment: @EugeneSh. Detail: `int32_t` is _optional_ for those rare platforms using non-2's complement.  A compliant platform need not have `int32_t`.

Comment: @EOF Good one, thanks. This is why I like SO. Every day something new...

Answer (score -1):

Don't get caught out and always use the definitions provided in stdint.h for specific bit size integers.

Consider this.

In gcc int32_t is defined as :

typedef signed int int32_t;

But unsigned int by default is 64 bits long.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    printf("sizeof(signed int) = %d\n", sizeof(signed int));
    printf("sizeof(int32_t) = %d\n", sizeof(int32_t));
}
```

Produces this output:

```
sizeof(signed int) = 8
sizeof(int32_t) = 4
```

So is a signed int 8 bytes or 4? And why does the length of int32_t differ from signed int when int32_t is a typedef of signed int?

Comment: *"unsigned int by default is 64 bits long"* On what platform?